# Show option dynamically according to the selected class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get my selected option class in some condition but I can't get it dynamically, I mean:

I want to replace the `class2` of `jQuery("#drop2 option).class2").show();` by `var actClass`

So I want : `jQuery("#drop2 option).actClass").show(); //actClass is my var.`

instead of :

`jQuery("#drop2 option).class2").show();`

```
//dropdown1
<select id="drop1" class="class1" name="class1">
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">---</option>
    <option class="class1" value="Val1">Val1</option>
    <option class="class2" value="Val2">Val2</option> //selected one
    <option class="class3" value="Val3">Val3</option>
</select>

//dropdown2
<select id="drop2" class="class1" name="class1">
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">---</option>
    <option class="class1" value="yop1">yop1</option>
    <option class="class2" value="yop2">yop2</option> 
    <option class="class3" value="yop3">yop3</option>
</select>

jQuery('#drop1').bind('change keyup', function() {
        var actClass = jQuery("#drop1 option:selected").attr('class'); //here i get the selected class exemple : class2
        jQuery("#drop2 option).class2").show(); //here I want to replace the .class2 by var actClass, I mean I get it dynamically
    });
```

Comment: You can not hide <option> cross browser. Will not work in IE or Safari. Choices are remove/replace or disable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string` `concatenation`

You can `concatenate` a string to a variable using `string concatenation`

```
Eg:  var a = "myname"

"test is"+a ==> "test is myname"
```

```js
 jQuery('#drop1').bind('change keyup', function() {
        var actClass = jQuery("#drop1 option:selected").attr('class'); //here i get the selected class exemple : class2
        jQuery("#drop2 option."+actClass).hide(); //regular browsers
        jQuery("#drop2 option."+actClass).remove(); // IE, safari browsers
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//dropdown1
<select id="drop1" class="class1" name="class1">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">---</option>
  <option class="class1" value="Val1">Val1</option>
  <option class="class2" value="Val2">Val2</option> //selected one
  <option class="class3" value="Val3">Val3</option>
</select>

//dropdown2
<select id="drop2" class="class1" name="class1">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">---</option>
  <option class="class1" value="yop1">yop1</option>
  <option class="class2" value="yop2">yop2</option>
  <option class="class3" value="yop3">yop3</option>
</select>
```

ps: as @charlietfl, mentioned option `show` `hide` may not work in all browsers, so you can `remove` and `create`.

You can also use `detach()`

```
 var opt=$("option").detach();
```

later you can `append()`

```
opt.appendTo( "select" );
```

**I added my example with remove please check**

Comment: Add some explanation! what was the problem?

Comment: Options can't be hidden in some browsers.

Comment: @charlietfl, added my explanation please check now

Comment: @charlietfl why Options can't be hidden in some browsers, it's ok in firefox and chrome

Comment: Fine. Now try it in IE or Safari. Is not a new issue. Has been that way for years

Comment: I m afraid, I m not having IE

Comment: @charlietfl I tried it in IE, So it also works but not nicely than the chrome of firefox, ie the length of the dropdwon doesn't adapt according to the list of options generated each time, you think to use `remove()` and `create()` is better that `show() and hide()` ?

Comment: @charlietfl `create(), remove()` doesn't work for me

Comment: @prc best approach is to clone existing and store them. No need to `create()` and without storing data you have nothing to use to create

Comment: I have no idea to how to do this @charlietfl

Comment: @prc, please check these links [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) and [cloning](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: @prc here's an example that has 3 selects and  value selected in one needs to be removed from others but of course any changes needs to put unused back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427798/how-to-preserve-all-select-elements-selected-values-in-jquery/48428530#48428530. Seems like your expected behavior is reverse of that but will give you idea

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` with drop down id and apply class  .

```js
jQuery('#drop1').bind('change keyup', function() {
  var actClass = jQuery("#drop1 option:selected").attr('class');
  var $this = jQuery("#drop2");
  $this.val($this.find('.' + actClass).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drop1" class="class1" name="class1">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">---</option>
  <option class="class1" value="Val1">Val1</option>
  <option class="class2" value="Val2">Val2</option> //selected one
  <option class="class3" value="Val3">Val3</option>
</select>

//dropdown2
<select id="drop2" class="class1" name="class1">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">---</option>
  <option class="class1" value="yop1">yop1</option>
  <option class="class2" value="yop2">yop2</option>
  <option class="class3" value="yop3">yop3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need jquery for that. The plain Javascript approach is to add/remove classes dynamically and it works fine:

```
document.querySelector("body").classList
document.querySelector("body").classList.add("new class")
document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("new class")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('#drop1').on('change', function() {
//get the class
var actClass=$('#drop1 option:selected").attr('class');
//remove the class class2 and set a new class
$('#drop2.class2").removeClass('class2').addClass(actClass);
});
```